# Como tomo los resultados de de mathprog usando GLPK

Tags: java, netbeans, glpk

estoy usando un archivo .mod que fue programado en el lenguaje Mathprog, estoy estabeleciendo la conexión con Java y tomando los resultados atraves de la biblioteca GLPK que lee el archivo .mod, pero el resultado me sale como texto en la consola y yo necesito de esos datos por lo menos en forma de arreglo, para ponerlos posteriormente en un formulario. Abajo les dejo el código que escribe los resultados y también les dejo una imagen de los reusltados, pero en forma de texto- Me gustaria mucho ser ayudado. Saludos][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJGfH.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJGfH.jpg)

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
           System.out.print("Usage: java Gmpl model.mod"+"\n");
           //System.out.println("line2");
            new LoadModel().LoadModel();
       }
    public void LoadModel() {
            glp_prob lp;
            glp_tran tran;
            glp_iocp iocp;
            int skip = 0;
            int ret;
            //GlpkCallback.addListener(this);
            lp = GLPK.glp_create_prob();
            System.out.println("Problem created");
            tran = GLPK.glp_mpl_alloc_wksp();
            ret = GLPK.glp_mpl_read_model(tran, fname , skip);
            if (ret != 0) {
                GLPK.glp_mpl_free_wksp(tran);
                GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
                throw new RuntimeException("Model file not found: " + fname);
            }
            // generate model
            GLPK.glp_mpl_generate(tran, null);
            // build model
            GLPK.glp_mpl_build_prob(tran, lp);
            // set solver parameters
            iocp = new glp_iocp();
            GLPK.glp_init_iocp(iocp);
            iocp.setPresolve(GLPKConstants.GLP_ON);
            // solve model
            ret = GLPK.glp_intopt(lp, iocp);
            int[] list=new int[50];
            int flags;
            // postsolve model
            if (ret == 0) {
                GLPK.glp_mpl_postsolve(tran, lp, GLPKConstants.GLP_MIP);
                n = GLPK.glp_get_num_cols(lp);
//                int GLPK.GLPK.glp_print_ranges(glp_prob*P, 50,list, flags, fnameList);
            }
            System.out.println("Columnas " + n);
            // free memory
            GLPK.glp_mpl_free_wksp(tran);
            GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
        }
        @Override
        public void callback(glp_tree tree) {
        int reason = GLPK.glp_ios_reason(tree);
        if (reason == GLPKConstants.GLP_IBINGO) {
            System.out.println("Better solution found");
```

Comment: Saludos Abel. Mi sugerencia es que primero analices como te entrega los resultados cada comando que usas. Porque muchas veces los datos se entregan usando separadores y puedes utilizar "split" para separarlos y extraerlos para posteriormente guardarlos en un arreglo que ya por defecto es asi cuando usas "split", es cuestion luego definir cuales son los valores de tu interes. Invierte tiempo en analizar cada comando que uses. Estaré pendiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias AndyC, he estado haciendo lo que usted me orientó, y hasta ahora no he podido, no tengo experiencia en esto.

Comment: Saludos abel, cuentame algo, con esos análisis exactamente que buscas hacer. Cual es el propósito de  lo que estas haciendo, esto lo digo porque si es lo que pienso te puedo mostrar una alternativa mucho mejor.